# mysql COUNT function on two or more columns as per true column value

Tags: mysql, count

I am trying to count the number of times the two columns have their  assigned value appears. The sql statement I have so far outputs wrong results. Take a look:

```
SELECT 
    UPPER(school.district) AS District_name, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT task1.wp_status) AS Status_New, 
    COUNT(task1.wp_type) AS Type_Bolehole 
FROM school 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN task1 ON school.s_name=task1.name 
WHERE task1.wp_status="New" OR task1.wp_type="Bolehole" 
GROUP BY district AND task1.wp_status="New" AND task1.wp_type="Bolehole" 
ORDER BY district;
```

The two tables am using are as below

```
School

s_name         district
matero          lusaka
kema            lusaka 
naka            kabwe

task1

name     wp_status   wp_type
matero     New      Bolehole                       
kema       New      Bolehole                    
naka       New    ProtectedWell
```

expected output

```
D_Name Status_New Type_Bolehole         
KABWE       1       2
LUSAKA      2       0
```

Comment: try changing your right outer join to a left join

Comment: The join is just okay. I can even use a WHERE clause. The issue is on the Count part as per column value.

Comment: but the count will be incorrect if you are not joining properly.

Comment: I have changed but still can't solve it. The second table is the one with more inclusive columns hence RIGHT JOIN Let's go guys.

Comment: your expected results dont make sense.. why 2 on kabwe? shouldnt it be lusaka?

Comment: Hooray for the poor, neglected RIGHT JOIN

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend writing the query like this:

```
SELECT UPPER(s.district) AS District_name, 
       SUM(t1.wp_status = 'New') AS Status_New, 
       SUM(t1.wp_type = 'Bolehole') AS Type_Bolehole 
FROM school s JOIN
     task1 t1
     ON s.s_name = t1.name 
WHERE t1.wp_status = 'New' or t1.wp_type = 'Bolehole'
GROUP BY UPPER(s.district)
ORDER BY District_Name;
```

This makes the following changes:

- Table aliases are introduced to make the query easier to read and write.
- The `join` is changed to an `inner join`.  You are selecting on one table and aggregating by the other, so it seems that the query expects a match in both tables.
- The `group by` is based on the actual expression used in the `select`.
- Conditional aggregation is used to get the two columns of counts.

Note:  This assumes that the sample results in the question are not correct.

Comment: The WHERE is completely redundant for the data provided

Comment: @JohnRuddell . . . True.  But keeping the `where` clause can make a query more efficient if it can make use of indexes (irrelevant for three rows but one presumes the actual data is larger).

Comment: true true... oh hey congrats on hitting 200k! :)

Answer (score 1):

you dont need a right join.. all you need is one conditional sum of the rows

```
SELECT
    UPPER(s.district) AS District_name,
    SUM(case when t.wp_status = 'New' then 1 else 0 end) AS Status_New,, 
    SUM(case when t.wp_type = 'Bolehole' then 1 else 0 end) AS Type_Bolehole 
FROM school s
LEFT JOIN task1 t ON s.s_name=t.name 
WHERE t.wp_status = 'New' or t.wp_type = 'Bolehole'
GROUP BY District_name
ORDER BY District_name;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08f4da/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT UPPER(school.district) AS District_name,
sum( task1.wp_status ="New") AS Status_New, 
sum(task1.wp_type="Bolehole") AS Type_Bolehole FROM school 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN task1 ON school.s_name=task1.name 
WHERE task1.wp_status="New" OR task1.wp_type="Bolehole" 
GROUP BY district  
ORDER BY district;
```

Also in your expected result set bolehole count for firt row should be 0 because task `naka` don't have type of bolehole

### [`Fiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5627a/3)

Comment: I was using a phone to post, the formatting was done by someone else please. At least the idea was gotten.

Comment: how did you answer 22 minutes ago? i just saw you post it?

Comment: @JohnRuddell Check the edit history. Deleted/undeleted.

Comment: Great thinking guys. Is there a way in which I can contact u as entities.

Comment: @mountain were on here.. if you want to ask a question we can always try and help.. you can use the `@` sign with our usernames if you want.. if you need more help i can give you my email.

Comment: @JohnRuddell i have answered before but i don't get the reason of downvote ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid i wasn't the downvoter :( i dont know who did :(

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid but I can off set it with an upvote :D there you go :)

Comment: @AirThomas also check the duration of deletion period it was for few moments and that deletion part belongs to evaluate fiddle results with expected output then i updated that part

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid yea i don't know who would downvote a perfectly good answer.. baffles me.

Comment: @John Ruddell drop your email address. I want some php report exports to excel, pdf etc help. Its a cumbersome question hence can't ask it on the main portal

Comment: @mountain if you could drop your email address. I can send you an email :) also please go through your questions and accept answers.. its what keeps the community clean :)

Comment: @John Ruddell, mountainclimbing1@gmail.com